# Dynamically generate a form (html)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to javascript / jQuery and I am trying to learn on how to create a form dynamically. After reading a bunch of tutorials I have got some code. I have jQuery loaded in the head tag.

```
//HTML
<body> 
<div class="container row-margin-top" id="question-container">
<button class="btn btn-default" type="button" onClick="javascript:createQuestion();">     
Create A Question </button>
</div>
</body>

//JavaScript
function createQuestion(){
var questionDiv = $(document.createElement('div'));
questionDiv.attr("id","questionNumber");
questionDiv.addClass("form-group");
questionDiv.html(function() {
    createQuestionContent();
});
$('#question-container').append(questionDiv);
    }

    function createQuestionContent(){
var html = "";
    html += '<label> Enter the first question </label>';
return html;
   }
```

Here is the jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/5pF8R/2/

The problem is that the label is not showing up, I tried to replace the label with < p > but that did not show up either.

Any help on what I am doing wrong would be great.

Thank You So much.

Comment: `return createQuestionContent();`

Comment: Or remove the anonymous function and just use `.html(createQuestionContent())`

Comment: I tried that, it did not work. questionDiv.html(function() {
    return createQuestionContent();
});

Comment: In jsFiddle: "No wrap - in <head>". Tip: check console.

Comment: jQuery handles the creation of elements for you. Instead of `$(document.createElement('div'));` you can simply: `$('<div/>', { id: "questionNumber", class: "form-group", ... })`.

Comment: Yes you are correct elclanrs it did work!

Comment: You should add your events _in JavaScript_ and you avoid this issue altogether. Check here http://api.jquery.com/on

Comment: elclanrs how would I do that in the above example ? Do not create jQuery div's at all ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want this **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ukifOLoV/1/edit)**:

```
function createQuestion(){
  $('<div/>',{
    id: 'questionNumber',
    class: 'form-group',
    html: createQuestionContent()
  }).appendTo('#question-container');
}

function createQuestionContent(){
return '<label> Enter the first question </label>';
}
```